# List<Long> to List<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist, ignite, classcastexception

I have a SQL query which returns an array.

```
List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();                                                                   
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql_query)) {
    listInteger = (List<Integer>) cursor.getAll().get(0);
}
```

Then I am trying to get the maximum value element in the array.

```
int max =  Collections.max(listInteger).intValue();
```

But this returns `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` error.

Then I tried

```
int max = (int) Collections.max(ventriTrigeminiBeatList).longValue();
```

and this also return the same error.

my SQL query is `Select sum( timestamp <= t1   and      timestamp >= t2), sum( timestamp <= t3   and      timestamp >= t4)  from db ;` I am querying an Ignite cache. Query is working well and it returns an array (ex: [3, 3, 3]). I am not able to use the sql MAX because I am using this `listInteger` later also.

Could someone tell me how to fix this. Thank You.

Comment: Why not also do the MAX in SQL?

Comment: Why not `long max = max(list).longValue()`?

Comment: I can't do MAX in sql because I am using this `listInteger` later also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL `SUM` function return type is mapped to `Long` for integral-type columns in Java, so you'll probably need to change the list to `List<Long>` and process it then.

See for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnbvy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `long` maximum and then just cast it to `int` if needed...

```java
long longMax =  Collections.max(listInteger).longValue();

Integer intMax = longMax == null ? null : Math.toIntExact(longMax); // This throws an exception if an overflow is present.
```